# Visual Studio Debugger Extensibility - Extending the Step Into

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

In the project, I have some specifics methods that every time you step into, you want to step into again into specific other method.

Example:

```
void Method1(...)
{
    ...
    ...
    Method2();
    ....
}

void Method2()
{
    ....
}
```

When you debug and step into Method1 you don't care for anything but just to reach Method2 and step into it.

Is there a way to extend the Debugger through an extension to complete this task? Basically, if I know in which method I am, I know where I want to go. I already have some LanguageExpressionEvaluator using IDkmLanguageExpressionEvaluator and IDkmLanguageExpressionCompiler.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Debugger.StepInto Method to achieve it. like this:

```
 DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
 EnvDTE.Debugger debugger = (EnvDTE.Debugger)dte.Debugger;
 debugger.StepInto(true);
```

For more information, please refer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.stepinto.aspx